# RETURNS and RETURN statements in METHODS in DS2 used in SAS

Tags: methods, sas

Could someone give me a very simple example of a METHOD in SAS DS2 where both RETURNS and RETURN words (statements) are used and it is clear what those words RETURNS and RETURN actually mean.

Answer (score 1):

- `returns` is a DS2 `method` statement definition specifier indicating what kind of value the method returns.
- `return` is a `DS2` statement that returns a value to the caller

**Example**

```
proc ds2;
  data _null_;
    method minus_one(double operand) returns double;
      return operand-1;
    end;
    method run();
      declare double x y;
      x = 1;
      y = minus_one(x);
      put x= y=;
    end;
  enddata;
run;
quit;
```

The `Proc DS2` documentation is a good place to start if you want basic information.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's clear I guess. "Return" returns 0 to down to the so called caller, so y=0, because x is understood as "operand" and "return" takes off a 1 from it.

Comment: The method body can be anything you want, and can even return instances of a package.  Similarly, the `in_out` argument modifier will let you write methods that affect the callers variables directly.